# Why Raid is not in the Hadoop 2.x?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

In the 0.22.0 version we can find the **raid** contrib, but it seems that the 2nd generation Hadoop (version 2.x) do not support hdfs-raid any longer, what's the reason?

Answer (score -1):

Hadoop has its own replication and checking mechanisms.The following is a quote from Alex Holme's **Hadoop In Practice**

> Using RAID, however, is strongly discouraged on the
>   DataNodes, because HDFS already has replication and error-checking built-in; but on
>   the NameNode it’s strongly recommended for additional reliability.